# Xcode 8 Error : Instance member 'row' cannot be used on type 'IndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to Swift and I have a problem in my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(data[IndexPath.row])"

        return cell!
    }
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `row` on the object not on the class, so lowercase "i":

```
cell?.textLabel?.text = "\(data[indexPath.row])"
```

Comment: very small but powerful